# How to create a "Deploy to Azure" button that uses a bicep instead of an JSON template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

When using plain JSON ARM templates we are able to create a `Deploy to Azure` button by embedding a link following this format:

```
[![Deploy to Azure](https://aka.ms/deploytoazurebutton)](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-quickstart-templates%2Fmaster%2F101-storage-account-create%2Fazuredeploy.json)
```

This results in an easy to use action, that even works on Stackoverflow

[image: Deploy to Azure]

Nice! But how can the same goal be achieved by using bicep templates?

Simply replacing the URL encoded part with a bicep file doesn't work. I am aware that bicep does a transpilation and produces a JSON-based ARM template.

However, as we are able to use the Azure CLI to directly deploy a bicep file, there might be another endpoint (like `https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri`) that does this for us.

Answer (score 2):

Portal doesn't currently support this.

As a work around you can use the output of `bicep build` and link the deploy button to the json file (that's what we'll be doing in the QuickStart repo until portal supports bicep natively).

Not ideal, but a point in time...

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, in a project of mine I created a GitHub workflow which build ARM template file based on Bicep template and *'automagically'* commit to repository using [Add&Commit](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-commit) action

This is a simple workflow template:

```
- name: Install Bicep build
  run: |
    curl -Lo bicepinstall
    https://github.com/Azure/bicep/releases/latest/download/bicep-linux-x64
    chmod +x ./bicepinstall
    sudo mv ./bicepinstall /usr/local/bin/bicep
    bicep --help

- name: Run Bicep build
  run: |
    bicep build deploy/main.bicep
    ls -l deploy/*.json
    
- uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v7.0.0
  with:
    author_name: github-actions
    author_email: '41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com'
    message: Update Bicep-ARM template
    add: deploy/main.json
```

Then in Readme file, you can insert standard Deploy button as described by bmoore-msft